# Is tag [vector-grid] appropriate for the Leaflet plugin for vector tile layers (L.VectorGrid)?

Tags: discussion, tags

The description of the [vector-grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-grid) tag says:

> Use for questions about vector grids which are also known as fishnets

However there are these questions, which are about the Leaflet plugin for vector tiles [L.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) and not about fishnets:

- [Adding a popup to features in a leaflet.vectorgrid layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348316/adding-a-popup-to-features-in-a-leaflet-vectorgrid-layer)
- [Using leaflet.VectorGrid protobuf and addLayer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348058/using-leaflet-vectorgrid-protobuf-and-addlayer)

Should they have a different tag? E.g. [vector-tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-tiles)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes questions about the Leaflet plugin should probably use the tag [vector-tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-tiles).  I have modified the tag excerpt for [vector-grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-grid) to also say:

> For questions about the Leaflet Plugin please use the tag "vector-tiles"